# Time for sunnah prayer before fard?

Tags: salat, nafl

When the sunnah mukkadah prayer before fard prayers are prayed i pray them at home and i give azan and iqama are they prayed between them or after iqama?

Comment: Iqama is -only- done before the fard prayer starts ... that should answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the time has come for that prayer, you can pray sunnah after that and before iqamah.

For example, 2 rakat sunnah before Fajr prayer - 
if fajr starts at 5:30am & sun rises at 7am then

- if you pray alone, then give adhan anytime between 5:30 and before 7am (e.g. 6:30am), then pray sunnah, then give iqamah and pray fard. Remeber to finish all prayers before sun rise, in this case.
- if you pray at mosque (or in Jamah), you need to pray after 5:30am and before iqamah.